# tabs fragment isn't displayed after reload

Tags: android

I'm creating an app with view pager and tabs:

At the first time clicked on "menu" item in the bottom navigation the text frag1, frag2 and frag3 are displayed as expected on the screen by clicking on the tabs and swiping (viewpager).

See image below:

[image]

But when I click an another item (e.g. home) and go back to "menu" item the text frag 1 and etc. are not display. See image below:[image]

MenuFragment with viewpageradapter:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fragManager);

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new MenuRecyclerViewFragment(), "FRAG1"); // `new MenuRecyclerViewFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new MenuRecyclerViewFragment(), "FRAG2"); // `new MenuRecyclerViewFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new MenuRecyclerViewFragment(), "FRAG3"); // `new MenuRecyclerViewFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;

}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>(); // this line can cause crashes
    public final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("text", mFragmentTitleList.get(position));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);  // this line can cause crashes
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

MenuRecylerViewFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_recycler_view, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String value = bundle.getString("text", "test");
        textView.setText(value);
    }


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second time you land to this fragment, getArguments() is not longer not null.
Use the savedInstanceState bundle instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewPagerAdapter class need to be extend by FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.
Look into more details of FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Fragments hosted by a ViewPager should be created by `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return new MenuRecyclerViewFragment();
        if(position == 1) return new MenuRecyclerViewFragment();
        if(position == 2) return new MenuRecyclerViewFragment();

        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return "FRAG1";
        if(position == 1) return "FRAG2";
        if(position == 2) return "FRAG3";
      
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }
}
```

2.) ViewPagers inside a Fragment (hosting Fragments) should be given `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `context.getSupportFragmentManager()` for it to work.